# Adding a individual host to a Group Policy Object(GPO) by modifying it using Vas Commands

Tags: rhel, gpo, qas

I want to add a rhel host to a GPO which is present in the domain through Vas Commands. Any help is appreciated for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vintela Authentication Services we can use vastool group command to add a host to the group and make sure the group must be linked to the Group Policy object you want to link to your host.

link: https://support.oneidentity.com/authentication-services/kb/129978/can-objects-other-than-users-be-added-to-or-removed-from-ad-groups-with-vastool-